# Square App Push API

Tags: api, push, square-connect

I use Square App for my store.
I know about Connect API to get the list of orders or some particular order information.
But I wonder if there is some push option: when a merchant has sold some item then square server sends to my server information about this order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for can be found in [Webhooks](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#webhooks-overview)